# How to handle random "getaddrinfo: Name or service not known" when sending data to firebase

Tags: ruby, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using this [firebase-ruby](https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby) gem.  Everything is fine most of the time but I think firebase occasionally has some issues and I get an exception with the above message. I have seen some posts on other sites mentioning similar issues but not really any good solutions.  Does anyone have a strategy that works and consistently writes to firebase databases without "ever" seeing these messages?

Since it only happens occasionally it is hard to do experiments to find a good solution.  My first thought is to retry with exponential back off,  buy I am really interested in a proven solution if anyone has one.

I am just creating the client with:

```
firebase = Firebase::Client.new(base_uri, "my-db-key")
```

and then writing the data with:

```
def push_to_database firebase, node, data
    begin
      response = firebase.push node, data
    rescue Exception => e  
      puts "failed to push to database, exception message is #{e.message}"
    end  
end
```